# Blazor server side upload file to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-blob-storage

I am using a file upload component that posts the file to an API controller and this works ok but i need to get the progres of the upload.

```
[HttpPost("upload/single")]
        public async Task SingleAsync(IFormFile file)
 
        {
            try
            {
              
                    // Azure connection string and container name passed as an argument to get the Blob reference of the container.
                    var container = new BlobContainerClient(azureConnectionString, "upload-container");

                    // Method to create our container if it doesn’t exist.
                    var createResponse = await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                    // If container successfully created, then set public access type to Blob.
                    if (createResponse != null && createResponse.GetRawResponse().Status == 201)
                        await container.SetAccessPolicyAsync(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.Blob);

                    // Method to create a new Blob client.
                    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

                    // If a blob with the same name exists, then we delete the Blob and its snapshots.
                    await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);

                // Create a file stream and use the UploadSync method to upload the Blob.

                uploadFileSize = file.Length;

                var progressHandler = new Progress<long>();
                progressHandler.ProgressChanged += UploadProgressChanged;

                    using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = file.ContentType },progressHandler:progressHandler);
                    }

                Response.StatusCode = 400;
           
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.StatusCode = 204;
                Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "File failed to upload";
                Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = e.Message;
            }
        }

        private double GetProgressPercentage(double totalSize, double currentSize)
        {
            return (currentSize / totalSize) * 100;
        }

        private void UploadProgressChanged(object sender, long bytesUploaded)
        {
            uploadPercentage = GetProgressPercentage(uploadFileSize, bytesUploaded);          
        }
```

I am posting this file and it does upload but the file upload progress event is inaccurate it says the file upload is complete after a few seconds when in reality the file takes ~90 secs on my connection to appear in the Azure Blob Storage container.

So in the code above i have the progress handler which works (I can put a break point on it and see it increasing) but how do I return this value to the UI?

I found one solution that used Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR but I can't manage to integrate this into my own code and I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track.

```
using BlazorReportProgress.Server.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading;

namespace BlazorReportProgress.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SlowProcessController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SlowProcessController> _logger;
        private readonly IHubContext<ProgressHub> _hubController;

        public SlowProcessController(
            ILogger<SlowProcessController> logger,
            IHubContext<ProgressHub> hubContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hubController = hubContext;
        }

        [HttpGet("{ClientID}")]
        public IEnumerable<int> Get(string ClientID)
        {
            List<int> retVal = new();

            _logger.LogInformation("Incoming call from ClientID : {ClientID}", ClientID);

            _hubController.Clients.Client(ClientID).SendAsync("ProgressReport", "Starting...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
            {
                _hubController.Clients.Client(ClientID).SendAsync("ProgressReport", loop.ToString());

                retVal.Add(loop);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            _hubController.Clients.Client(ClientID).SendAsync("ProgressReport", "Done!");

            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

I read the Steve Sandersen blog but this says not to use the code as its been superceded by inbuilt blazor functionality.

My application is only for a few users and so i'm not too worried about backend APIs etc, If the upload component used a service not a controller I could more easily get the progress, but the compoents all seem to post to controllers.

Can anyone please enlighten me as to the best way to solve this?

Comment: If you are not looking for any API, then you can try this by calculating the percentage as below 
(blobToUpload.ContentLength/totalBytesUploaded )*100

Comment: Thanks and it may be the simplest way to bin the api controller(the immediate difficulty Is that the component (Radzen Upload) uses the post method so I will need to use another component..  
BUT just out of interest how would I get the progress back from the controller?  I have searched high and low and nowhere is this explained.